How to create a new menu in Docusaurus and different sidebar content
in my project, I haven't been able to setup a new menu with different sidebar content

In this case I already have a menu with content in the sidebar, but I want to add a new menu, with different sidebar content, my expectation like bellow

How to config `docusaurus.config.js`

did you check this https://docusaurus.io/docs/sidebar/multiple-sidebars ?
